# Memory is not cleared after destroying EGL context which shares data with other context

Tags: java, android, memory, google-cardboard, egl

I'm working on 3d model viewer for android. When I open model, non-VR view (RenderView) which extends GLSurfaceView loads. Here is context factory which I use in setEGLContextFactory() method in this view (log calls and error checks are ommited):

```
public static class ContextFactory implements GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory {
    private static int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;

    public EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        int[] attrib_list = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
        EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
                attrib_list);

        //Reference is need to use this context as share_context parameter.
        RenderView.context = context;
        return context;
    }

    public void destroyContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLContext context) {
        egl.eglDestroyContext(display, context);
    }
}
```

Next I press 'VR' button and view which extends CardboardView (which extends GLSurfaceView) loads. Here it's context factory:

```
public static class ContextFactory implements GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory {
    private static int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;

    public EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        int[] attrib_list = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE };  
        EGLContext newContext = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, RenderView.context, attrib_list);
        return newContext;
    }

    public void destroyContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLContext context) {
        egl.eglDestroyContext(display, context);
    }
}
```

As you can see it uses RenderView context as share_context parameter in eglCreateContext() method. I also setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true) on non-VR view so context isn't lost after i switch to VR mode.
Next i press 'Back" button and we return to non-VR view (RenderView).

All EGLCOntextFactory methods work fine and get called when needed. VR context gets properly destroyed when i switch back to non-VR mode but **memory it consumes is not get cleared**.

Now i go to VR mode again and another context is created which consume memory. I go back to non-VR mode, VR context get destroyed but memory is not get cleared again. So each time I switch to VR mode more and more memory get consumed (about 17 MB per switch).

**Memory is totaly cleared** (it doesn't matter how much VR contexts were created) **only afted non-VR context (which shares data with VR contexts) is destroyed** (when i close non-VR view and go to model picking screen).

So the question is why context memory isn't cleared after destruction if context is 'based' on another context and only clears after 'base' context is destroyed? And is there way to resolve this problem **by means of GL methods?**